# Angular's ng-options work incorrect | Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular's ng-options works incorrect.

It must render select like this:

```
<option value="1" label="Not available">Not available</option>
<option value="3" selected="selected" label="Available">Available</option>
```

But it does not. Value keys aren't match and selected tag doesn't work.

What I'm doing wrong here?

**Product model object from db**

```
Object {id: "7", name: "Some name", category_id: "1", img_big: "uploads/products/5552f2ba31694@big.jpeg", img_thumb: "uploads/products/5552f2ba31694@thumb.jpeg"…}
```

**isAvailable object**

```
$rootScope.isAvailableScope = [
    {
        status: 1,
        name  : 'Not available'
    },
    {
        status: 3,
        name  : 'Available'
    }
]
```

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control"
        ng-model="product.is_available"
        ng-options="isAvailable.status as isAvailable.name for isAvailable in isAvailableScope"
        required>
    <option value="">Choose</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Why `$rootScope` and not `$scope`?

Answer (score 0):

Change `$rootScope` to `$scope`. You're in the controller and within it's scope.

```
$rootScope.isAvailableScope = [
    {
        status: 1,
        name  : 'Not available'
    },
    {
        status: 3,
        name  : 'Available'
    }
]
```

to ...

```
$scope.isAvailableScope = [
    {
        status: 1,
        name  : 'Not available'
    },
    {
        status: 3,
        name  : 'Available'
    }
]
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dcodesmith/avaf61kd/)**

Comment: It doesn't matter. $rootScope is the main scope which is available in every controller. In your fiddle the same problem. Key values don't match..

Comment: Could you create a fiddle showing the issue is exactly?